# What strategy to adopt to handle connection loss in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

We have a lot(~15) WCF services on the same server. To connect to them, we have a class(which I named `ClientConnection`). This class manage all the different service on the client side to one particular server.

This class is responsible of creating the Channel(and their bindings) for every service that is asked(and cache them).

Now, what if the connection broke(let's imagine that one switch was down, or one server is too busy to answer), I would like to have a fallback strategy.

It means to detect that it brokes, and then try to restore the connection.

Currently I've a "watchdog" in this class that verify that it can reach the remote service, if not it raise an event.

When I get this event, what should I do? Refresh the channel? Dispose it and create a new one? Also, since I've 10-15 active services to the same server, should I restore them anyway?

I think I should not be the first one to have this issue, but I struggle to find a good strategy on how to manage all thoses issues

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good fit for the [Circuit Breaker Pattern](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CircuitBreaker.html)

The long and short of it is that you essentially have something that tolerates failures with retry behaviour up to a point, and then has a back-off behaviour to gradually try to re-establish the connection.

Comment: I see, it is what I was wanting to do, without knowing the name. But how should I put this in practice? Because I don't want to but this kind of try/catch on every call, and how should I manage the other services if one fails?

Comment: @J4N it is pretty much like a try catch on each call, but that's always going to be the case if you want to have that sort of resilience, and you'd basically have a facade layer that goes through the circuit breaker, so every service you call would have its own breaker. Obviously the requirements will dictate how complex it will be.

Comment: But if one service fail, the other will also fail, no?

Comment: Well, it depends, if you're calling one after another then possibly if they're dependent upon the result from the previous call, but then if the first one fails you just don't call the next one until the first one works again...?